# How to create disk partition starting at 128 sector?

Tags: usb-drive, partitioning, format, mbr

I have accidentally lost partition table after inserting my USB flash to some faulty computer.
For this flash `testdisk` can't find anything and says that `Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55`. And `gdisk` can't find any partition table on it.

But I have two flashes of this model and did not changed their partitioning. So I checked second flash and saw that it has first single primary FAT32 partition starting at 128 sector (!).

So my idea is the following: recreate the MBR partition table using some low-level tool without formatting it.

Which tool should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found only one application able to set too small value of the starting sector.

It is named `sfdisk` (from `utils-linux` package, usually preinstalled).

The syntax for needed action is the following:

```
$ sudo sfdisk /dev/sdX

>>> 128,,0xb
>>> write
```

where

- `128` is starting sector (followed by comma `,`);
- no symbol means auto size (followed by comma `,`);
- `0xb` is a short marking for `W95 FAT32` partition type.

to follow the format from help (or see [`man sfdisk`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/sfdisk.8.html)):

> ````
>    <start>  Beginning of the partition in sectors, or bytes if
>             specified in the format <number>{K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y}.
>             The default is the first free space.
>
>    <size>   Size of the partition in sectors, or bytes if
>             specified in the format <number>{K,M,G,T,P,E,Z,Y}.
>             The default is all available space.
>
>    <type>   The partition type.  Default is a Linux data partition.
>             MBR: hex or L,S,E,X shortcuts.
>             GPT: UUID or L,S,H shortcuts. ```
> ````

and finally I asked system to reread changed partition table:

```
$ sudo partprobe
```

---

Notes: other tools such as `cfdisk` and `fdisk` allows to set starting sector as >= 2048.